# In Play Scala Call a controller method from another method

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following controller defined in Play Scala 2.2.

```
object Blog extends Controller {
    val postForm = Form(
        mapping(
            "title" -> nonEmptyText,
            "content" -> nonEmptyText
            )(Post.apply)(Post.unapply)
    )

    def defaultList = Action {
        list(DateTime.now())
    }

    def list(date: DateTime) = Action {
      Ok(views.html.posts(Posts.all(), postForm))
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on compilation:

`Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Can I call one controller method from another? I'm VERY new to Scala and Play.

Comment: Can you try `def defaultList = list(DateTime.now())` (without the Action). It's just a hunch that you're nesting two Actions into each other and that's whats causing the error. Also can you maybe point us to the line the compiler has the problem with?

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap in this way, because any action in play2 takes a function: `Request => Result` so from request to result, and in your code you return another `Action`, so it won't compile. You can do like @Akos Krivachy propose, put your call of `list Action` inside a function not an Action and then bind this function to some route for example. In this case you may have only one route to bind your `defaultList` function. Or you can leave your `defaultList` as an `Action` and use a redirect inside:

```
def defaultList = Action {
        Redirect(routes.Application.list(DateTime.now()))
    }
```

Note : you need to indicate routes for both `Actions` in `route` file